# MFC controls hide on Windows 7 basic theme

Tags: c++, windows-7, mfc, themes

Can anyone please tell me why MFC applications are not displaying correctly in Windows 7 basic theme ?

EDIT: Is there anyone who can guess the problem ?

EDIT:

- Im using vs2008 (same version is used to create this app).
- This particular window is DLL based.For creating that DLL I added these in the Stdafx.h

.

```
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_IA64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='ia64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
```

- This problem occurs only in this window.
- This window is based on CDialog, inside OnInitDialog() I'm doing these,

.

```
CDialog::OnInitDialog();
AfxInitRichEdit();
// And Create three more child windows.
```

- This is how it displayed in basic theme.

[image]

But, it is working nicely when I changed to Windows Aero theme.

[image]
What should be the solution ?

EDIT: Anyone please ?

Comment: @Morpheus, Are you sure you do invalidate the window?

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan, I'm not sure what do you mean ? Could you please explain me ?

Comment: Give more information -> Version of Visual Studio you used to create the project and (and also the current version) -> Did you include Manifest for your project? -> Is it only specific with a single control or with all controls in the window? -> If it's for single control, give more details about the control

Comment: @sarat, Thanks for pointing out. I added more information.

Comment: It seems like the window is not updated, so the controls and window background are not repainted. You should check your paint code (if you handle WM_PAINT correctly, if you update the window after drawing in it etc).

Comment: @morpheus - Please check your project settings whether it's UNICODE or not. The application must be in UNICODE to support common controls and manifest. You can see the definition in stdafx.h

Answer (score 0):

- It's advisable to initialize richedit control in the InitInstance function of Application class. I am not sure it will work fine with OnInitDialog.
- Check your program /DLL is UNICODE code or not from the project settings.
- By default Visual Studio 2008 will generate manifest for the program (for EXEs).
- Manifest must be embedded only if the application is UNICODE.

Please check this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and led down here by google, but none of the answers solved the problem. Then I fixed it only by changing the `transparent` attribute of the window/controls to FALSE. Can you try it out?